# How to handle responseText for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a javascript function as below which I hosted it at S3

```
function myFunction() {

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET","https://id.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/lambdafunction", true);
xhttp.send();

}
```

And this `lambdafunction` is written in `Node.js`as below

```
'use strict';

console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

let response = {
    statusCode: '200',
    body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'you messed up!' }),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};
context.succeed(response);
//callback(null, context);  // Echo back the first key value
//callback('Something went wrong');
};
```

What I expect was that div with id testing will be replaced by `error: 'you messed up!` but nothing happened? May I know which part may have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the api for the (very) old node v.0.10.42.

It seems more likely that you would be using the newer version so you should have:

```
callback(null, JSON.stringify({ error: 'you messed up!' })); 
// if you are not using proxy integration
```

*or*

```
callback(null, response)
// if you set up the function with proxy integration
```

If this doesn't help, it would be useful to know what you get when you access the url directly and if you are seeing anything in the AWS logs. You should also be able to directly invoke the lambda function from the AWS console, which makes testing easier.